# Como remover CEP e país de uma string

Tags: javascript, string, regex, aplicação-web

Estou utilizando JavaScript para manipular algumas *strings* que vem de uma API e preciso remover o CEP e o país de uma dessas *strings*.

Basicamente, eu recebo a frase assim:

```
"R. Anderson Ferreira dos Réis, 122 - Conj. Hab. Joel Marques, Tauá - CE, 63660-000, Brasil"
```

E preciso tratar para ficar sem o CEP e o país, assim:

```
"R. Anderson Ferreira dos Réis, 122 - Conj. Hab. Joel Marques, Tauá - CE"
```

Sei que é possível utilizar o método replace() para isso, mas a regex que eu usei não funcionou.
Eu tentei algo desse tipo para retirar o cpf:

```
let text = "R. Anderson Ferreira dos Réis, 122 - Conj. Hab. Joel Marques, Tauá - CE, 63660-000, Brasil"

const result = text.replace(/\d\d((\d\d\d)|(\.\d\d\d-))\d\d\d, '')
```

Mas esse código não funciona.

Alguém saberia como fazer isso da forma correta?

Comment: Acredito que no título da sua pergunta seja CEP ao invés de CPF, certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão abaixo busca 5 números na sequência, um traço, mais 3 números na sequência e depois tudo que estiver a frente. Talvez possa ajudar mas dependendo da variação dos seus inputs pode ser necessário ajustar a expressão.

```js
const input = 'R. Anderson Ferreira dos Réis, 122 - Conj. Hab. Joel Marques, Tauá - CE, 63660-000, Brasil';

console.log(
   input.replace(
     /((,\s)?\d{5}-\d{3}.*)/g,
     ''
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes resolver de uma forma bem simples, não sei se a mais correta, seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
var texto = "R. Anderson Ferreira dos Réis, 122 - Conj. Hab. Joel Marques, Tauá - CE, 63660-000, Brasil"

var objeto = texto.split(',')
```

Teria sua *string* separada por `,` em um objeto e descartaria as que não precisa através dos indices, depois podes só concatenar os indices.